# Web.py sending and requesting files for S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, scalability, web.py

I'm building a web service using web.py, with S3 to store files. One part of my web service has a 'commit' method (similar to that of SVN/Git) that takes in a list of files in a user's local folder and compares them to the files that have currently been uploaded (by md5 hashing the local files, and keeping a database record of hashes of remote files). The client then zips the files that have been added or modified since the last 'commit' and uploads this zip to the server. The server then unzips this and puts the files where they should be, updating the database with the new hashes.

However, I want this to be a scalable web service and handling massive zip archives will be a problem. I've thought of two possible approaches:

1. Deal with files one at a time - server requests each file when last file has been uploaded.
2. Find a way of bypassing my server and letting the user upload straight to S3. However user should still be authenticated on my server!

I'm very new to web services so any advice would be appreciated. Needless to say, I'd like these transactions to be as cheap as possible in terms of memory and processing time.